# Override PasswordSignInAsync in Custom SignInManager (ASP.NET Core 2)

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

A funny thing happend to me. So funny, I'm still out of control.

Short story: 
inspired by https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/extending-the-asp-net-core-identity-signinmanager I created a custom `SignInManager` with an override of the  `PasswordSignInAsync` method. Background of this requirement is to have a second log in page (with a PIN). However, when I'm trying to login from the new page (LoginPin.cshtml), the `PasswordSignInAsync` is not hit.

And here's the funny thing: when I do the same from the Login.cshtml page it is hit!

Long story:

```
public class AuditableSignInManager<TUser> : SignInManager<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    private readonly UserManager<TUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public AuditableSignInManager(UserManager<TUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> claimsFactory, 
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<TUser>> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
    {
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
        _db = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
    }

    public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        //skipped for readability reasons 
var result = await base.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs & Dependency Injection:

```
services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, AuditableSignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Login.cshtml.cs

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // skipped

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    }
}
```

LoginPin.cshtml.cs

```
public class LoginModelPin : PageModel
{


private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModelPin> _logger;

public LoginModelPin(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModelPin> logger)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(usrPwd, usrPwd, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
}
}
```

To be honest: it is not funny anymore. Could someone point me to the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

N.

Comment: Just to clarify, the OnPostAsync from LoginModelPin is hit but the method PasswordSignInAsync is not called? Or it's called and base.PasswordSignInAsync is not hit?

Comment: OnPostAsync from LoginModelPin is hit and calls base.PasswordSignInAsync (=SignInManager) whereas OnPostAsync from LoginModel calls PasswordSignInAsync  from AuditableSignInManager

Comment: Did you solve it? Quickly glancing at the problem what comes to mind is that there must be some sort of overload in the SignInManagerAsync that is not getting fired because the parameters are not triggering it. Check to see if you are overwriting similar SignInManagerAsync because other method could be firing.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. Nope, I did not solve it. Just created a new project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `AddSignInManager<TSignInManager>>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identitybuilderextensions.addsigninmanager?view=aspnetcore-2.2